# Function call macro in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

If a function, say `foo()`, is called in different ways on varius platforms, is it bad practice to use a macro?

For example:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define ffoo(a) foo(0)
#else
#define ffoo(a) foo(a)
#endif
```

Comment: A lot of big projects do this. For example Wireshark.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in C or C++.  The answer is (probably) different.

Comment: I think it's more often needed if you must change the name of the function (perhaps to avoid link time name clashes, or because of naming conventions). IIRC I have also seen function names mangled with defines for the linker in order to improve run time lookup speeds.

Comment: Its really hard to avoid sometimes which is why the pre-processor will be around for a long time to come. But if you can avoid it, do.

Comment: It's above all in C++ i'm looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Macros are not aware of scopes or the context they are put in, they run before the actual compilation phrase and replaces the occurrences to it.

Let's imagine you want to use a `ffoo` name somewhere else, perhaps as a method name to a class, or even another function:

```
int MyClass::ffoo(int y) {}
```

That would unexpectedly cause a compilation error because `ffoo(...)` would be expanded to a function call, wrong tokens in the wrong place.

A very common and annoying example of this is a macro named `min` and `max` defined in the Windows API, once you try to use the C++ `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` function for instance you'll find the bad design.

Your better alternative would be an inline function as they respect the language semantics, after all they are functions.

```
#ifdef WIN32
inline int ffoo(int a) { return foo(0); }
#else
inline int ffoo(int a) { return foo(a); }
#endif
```

If you are in a C89 enviroment that does not support the `inline` keyword you could perhaps use `static`, given the size of this call it'd not hurt.

Comment: The example doesn't hold, at least not with my gcc. `int ffoo;` does not collide with a function macro.

Comment: @PeterSchneider True, I've used a function macro in a identifier context, I'll correct the answer to put it in a function context.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ it is considered bad practice, there you have so many other possibilities like inheritance, overloading etc that it is not really needed.

Answer (score 2):

Creating macros using `#define` has been known to cause undefined behavior. I would recommend using templates instead of macros.

Simple example from the book "Effective C++":

```
#define CALL_WITH_MAX(a,b) f((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Produces different behavior when called like this (try it):

```
CALL_WITH_MAX(++a,b); // a is incremented twice
CALL_WITH_MAX(++a,b+10); // a is incremented once
```

If you are using C however, you are more limited as you don't have templates or object oriented workarounds.

Comment: I would be more inclined to call that unexpected behavior, not undefined behavior.  And, you're example depends on what is stored in `a` and `b` when you call that macro.

Comment: @Degustaf Yes, there is no undefined behavior in the example. The evaluation of the second( or third ) operand is sequenced after evaluation of the first one.